# CSS slider animation not working only in safari?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i am implementing a css only slider (no jquery) in wordpress based on this code: http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/kFoGw

The problem the slider is not doing transitions in safari, working fine in other browsers such as chrome, FF.

```
<div id="captioned-gallery">
    <figure class="slider">
                <figure>
            <img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/utah-peak.jpg" alt>
            <figcaption>Integer vitae lectus accumsan, egestas dui eget, ullamcorper urn. In feugiat tortor at turpis rhoncus tincidunt. Duis sed porttitor ante, eget venenatis lectus.</figcaption>       </figure>

                <figure>
            <img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/hobbiton-lake.jpg" alt>
            <figcaption>Utah Mountains Valley in United States</figcaption>     </figure>

            ... 

            </figure>
</div>
```

and the css rules

/* Frontpage Slider */

```
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

figure { 
  margin: 0; 
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}
div#captioned-gallery { 
  width: 100%; overflow: hidden; 
}
figure.slider { 
  position: relative; width: 500%; 
  font-size: 0; animation: 20s slidy infinite; 
}
figure.slider figure { 
  width: 20%; height: auto;
  display: inline-block;  position: inherit; 
}
figure.slider img { width: 100%; height: auto; }

figure.slider figure figcaption { 

  position: absolute; top:30%; left:10%; width:75%; text-align:center;
  line-height: 160%; 

  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  color: #fff; 
  font-size: 3vw; padding: .6rem; 
}
```

The slider example in codepen is working fine in safari but there is a problem in my code.

I am hooking up all the stylesheets and scripts in wordpress like this (note the order)

```
wp_enqueue_style('pure-min', get_template_directory_uri().'/pure/pure-min.css');
wp_enqueue_style('pure-responsive-min', get_template_directory_uri().'/pure/grids-responsive-min.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'default', get_stylesheet_uri() ); // default stylesheet

wp_register_style('ezy-font-light','http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300|Oswald:300');
wp_register_style('ezy-font-dark','http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Oswald');

wp_enqueue_style('css-font-awesome', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `-webkit-` prefix.

```
 @-webkit-keyframes slidy {
```

AND

```
 -webkit-animation: slidy 5s;
```

Learn all prefixes:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: i see that the example in codepen is working fine in safari without webkit prefix?

Comment: Your codepen has the `prefixfree` or the `autoprefixer` activated. This is a library that writes automatically the prefixes. In this case is prefixfree that's activated. You should test without prefixers, click on SETTINGS > CSS on your codepen

Comment: i tried the prefix, it is not doing the transition. Something else is wrongi guess?

Comment: Is not only the @-webkit-keyframes, read the entire css-tricks.com page that I share you. You must to write prefixes in all your css that appears an animation, not only in keyframes. It solves the problem

Comment: Please, if this solve your problem mark as valid answer. Thank you!